# How do I get the name of the parent folder in a command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, command-prompt

I'm in a Windows Command Line and want the parent folder in a variable.

Assuming current directory is "C:\foo\bar", how can I get the value "bar"?

I'm expecting something like a "find last backslash in CD and that's it".

And please, no powershell references; I want plain old Windows Command Line operations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My solution uses substitution and works for root directory as well:

```
call set PARENT_DIR=%CD%
set PARENT_DIR=%PARENT_DIR:\= %
set LAST_WORD=
for %%i in (%PARENT_DIR%) do set LAST_WORD=%%i
echo %LAST_WORD%
```

Comment: You beat me to it and you have a nicer solution - I'm not sure mine works for root folders.

Answer (score 5):

This appears to get the current directory name, and stores it in the environment variable `bar`:

```
for %i in (%CD%) do set bar=%~ni
```

This works because `%CD%` contains the current directory, and `%~n` strips the output of the for loop (looping for one value, `%CD%`) to the 'file name' portion.

(Note, if you're using this in a batch file, use `%%i` and `%%~ni` instead.)

This doesn't, however, work for the root directory of a drive, it will instead unset `bar`, as `%~ni` will evaluate to nothing.

Comment: It also breaks the folder name if the folder name contains a period (full stop). But otherwise, it's ace!

Comment: Use `%~nxi` to support directories with extensions.

Comment: Doesn’t work if there are spaces. I got it to work (double-`%` because in a batch file) when I wrote: `FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ("%CD%") DO SET bar=%%~nxi`

Answer (score 2):

@pmod's answer (I lack the rep to comment) may work for root directories, but it doesn't work if there are spaces in the names.

Here's a slightly improved version (substituting / for space before splitting, then reverse substituting when finished).

```
call set PARENT_DIR=%CD%
set PARENT_DIR=%PARENT_DIR: =/%
set PARENT_DIR=%PARENT_DIR:\= %
set LAST_WORD=
for %%i in (%PARENT_DIR%) do set LAST_WORD=%%i
set LAST_WORD=%LAST_WORD:/= %
echo %LAST_WORD%
```

Answer (score 1):

Pmod has a neater solution; I'm not sure mine works for root folders. But I thought I'd include it here for people to see.

```
set myPath=%cd%
pushd ..
set parentPath=%cd%
popd
echo myPath = "%myPath%"
echo parentPath = "%parentPath%"
call set myDir=%%myPath:%parentPath%\=%%
echo myDir = "%myDir%"
```